# What happens to a piece of data if you use zlib to decompress it, but it isn't compressed in the first place?

Tags: zlib

If you decompress data with zlib that isn't compressed, does anything happen?

If it does in fact change the data, how do you check if data is zlib zipped in the first place?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There would need to be a valid header. Extremely unlikely that this could ever happen unless it was an accurately structured (compressed) data stream, so it would be invalid data to inflate.

Comment: Encrypted data will also not compress, unless it is a really crappy cipher.